# AngularJS: $http and $q promises work differently

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have `getUsers` function in my service:

```
function getUsers() {
    return $q( (resolve, reject) => {
        $timeout(() => {
            let flag = true;

            flag ? resolve(users) : reject("Error Users");

        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

and `getExampleResponse()` based on `$http` service

```
    function getExampleResponse() {
        return $http
            .get("./example.json");
    }
```

I know that `$http.get` should return promise. In my controller I have following code:

```
    let userPromise = myService.getUsers(),
        examplePromise = myService.getExampleResponse();

    $q.all([userPromise, examplePromise])
        .then(getAllDataSuccess)
        .catch(getTasksError)
        .finally(getTasksComplete);

    function getAllDataSuccess(dataArray) {
        console.log(dataArray[0]); // I have user object here
        console.log(dataArray[1]); // I have promise object here
    }
```

So after `then` callback in one case I have desired object, in other case I proceed having promise. What is wrong?

Comment: It is unlikely so. Because [$http essentially returns $q promise](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/ng/http.js#L964). A plunk would help.

Comment: reading [this](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/) suggests HttpPromises (what $http etc return) are not the same as $q promises - seems you want to `return $http.get("./example.json").then(response => response.data);`

Comment: @JaromandaX, thank you! It helped me

Answer (score -1):

in `getUsers()` you are returning $q. If you want to pass promise then return

```
function getUsers() {
    var d = $q.defer();
    // Your code
    return d.promise;
}
```

Comment: It is correct. What you're suggesting is an antipattern, https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern .

Comment: $http.get() promise is different from $q